# Error while using latest versions of cucumber/protractor-cucumber-framework

Tags: node.js, protractor, cucumber

I'm working in a project where an old versions of `cucumber` and `protractor-cucumber-framework` are used - 1.3.3 & 1.0.2 respectively. I'd like to use the latest versions of these packages, but when I run tests (which work quite fine on old versions) on

`cucumber@4.2.1` & `protractor-cucumber-framework@5.0.0`

I get the following error:

```
Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at EventDataCollector.storePickle (C:\projectPath\node_modules\cucumber\src\formatter\helpers\event_data_collector.js:48:30)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at C:\projectPath\node_modules\cucumber\src\cli\helpers.js:56:26
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at C:\projectPath\node_modules\cucumber\src\cli\helpers.js:51:10
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at Generator.tryCatcher (C:\projectPath\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
    at PromiseSpawn._promiseFulfilled (C:\projectPath\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\generators.js:97:49)
    at C:\projectPath\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\generators.js:201:15
    at getTestCases (C:\projectPath\node_modules\cucumber\lib\cli\helpers.js:96:18)
    at C:\projectPath\node_modules\cucumber\src\cli\helpers.js:30:13
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at Generator.tryCatcher (C:\projectPath\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
    at PromiseSpawn._promiseFulfilled (C:\projectPath\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\generators.js:97:49)
    at Promise._settlePromise (C:\projectPath\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:574:26)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\projectPath\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (C:\projectPath\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:693:18)
    at Async._drainQueue (C:\projectPath\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:133:16)
    at Async._drainQueues (C:\projectPath\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:143:10)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (C:\projectPath\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17:14)
    at runCallback (timers.js:666:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:639:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:611:5)

[18:54:29] E/launcher - BUG: launcher exited with 1 tasks remaining
[18:54:29] 'cucumber-start' errored after 18 s
[18:54:29] Error in plugin 'gulp-protractor'
Message:
    protractor exited with code 100
```

I've searched in Google, but it didn't help me. It'll be great if someone can say what the problem can be.

I'm using Windows7 x64, by the way. NodeJS version is 7.7.1, protractor - 5.3.2.

Cucumber options are:

```
cucumberOpts: {
        require: [
            './features/step_definitions/**/*.steps.js',
            './features/support/hooks.js',
            './features/support/env.js'
        ],
        tags: false,
        format: 'json:./reports/cucumber.json',
        profile: false,
        ignoreUncaughtExceptions: true,
        'no-source': true
    },
```

Comment: Please show  the `cucumberOpts` in your protractor conf.js

Comment: cucumberOpts are added to the description

Comment: Can you zip this folder: C:\projectPath\node_modules\cucumber, and commit it to github where I can get.  I intend to look into the source code around `cucumber\src\formatter\helpers\event_data_collector.js:48:30`.  Even I also installed that version on local, but I got different folder structure as yours.

Comment: The same scenario works quite fine when older versions are used: `cucumber@1.3.3` & `protractor-cucumber-framework@1.0.2`. Can it still be a syntax error?

Comment: After several experiments I can say - Yes, this happens for any scenario and feature file. Also, I can zip and upload the `cucumber` folder to github, but I'm confused, because I can't find `C:\projectPath\node_modules\cucumber\src` folder, although it is mentioned in the error message(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171095/discussion-between-atsvetk-and-yong).

Comment: Can  you zip your project folder include `node_modules`. but without secure information like password, and put it on github, I can debug on local.

Comment: Probably, there is smth wrong with chat, will write here: github.com/Atsvetk/misc - Here is my cucumber folder from project's node_modules & part of package.json (node_modules are too huge to upload even zipped)

Comment: I used your package.json to build a local project with simple feature file and step definition file.  And use your Nodejs (v8.11.1) and npm(5.6.0) version for `npm install` and execute script.  The running pass.  Additionally, I compared my installed `cucumber` with the one in your github by tool: `BeyondCompare`. All files are same.   You can get the example project from https://github.com/yongcy/stackoverflow/tree/master/misc, and run on your local,  If that issue not happen,  I think it comes from your feature file or other dependencies not included in my project.

Comment: You can commit a feature file of yours which report that error to your github, I can  run it on my local. Seems I get the wrong version of your Nodejs, it should be  `7.7.1`, described in your question. I get `v8.11.1` from the package.json of cucumber in your github. I will try nodejs `7.7.1`

Comment: my project work well on nodejs 7.7.1 too